# Fourier coefficients of translation $f(x+y)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am trying to express the Fourier coefficients of $f(x+y)$ in terms of the Fourier coefficients of $f(x)$. I have

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x+y) e^{-inx} dx = \int_{-\pi+y}^{\pi+y} f(u) e^{-in(u-y)} du = e^{iny}\int_{-\pi +y}^{\pi+y}f(u)e^{-inu}du $$ $=2 \pi e^{iny}\hat{f}(n)$.

Is this correct? I was under the impression that the Fourier coefficients were supposed to be translation-invariant, which is the main reason for why I am doubting this result.

Comment: it looks correct, except the $2\pi$ factor, where does this comes from ?

Comment: It comes from knowing that $\hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int f(x) e^{inx}$. (At least that is the idea so please correct me if it is wrong :) )

Comment: When $y = 0$ your formula gives $\hat{f}(n) = 2 \pi \hat{f}(n)$ :) 
But else I think it is not surprising that this factor appears. The coefficients are only translation invariant is a multiple of $2\pi$.

Comment: I am feeling like a bit of an idiot (blaming lack of sleep) but if $y=0$, doesn't my formula give $2\pi \hat{f}(n) = 2\pi \hat{f}(n)$ since I am not dividing by $1/(2\pi)$ in front of the integral?

Comment: Also, I can't upvote comments yet, but thank you for clarifying regarding the translation invariance.

Comment: No problem ! In fact, you are right, I was forgetting that for get the coefficient you need to divide by $2 \pi$, so this looks perfectly correct to me.

Comment: Are you considering $f$ as a periodical function, and thus we are speaking of coefficients of a Fourier **series**, or considering the Fourier **transform** ?

Comment: As a periodical function. I think that might be why I was confused, because I believe the Fourier transform is translation-invariant...

Comment: I wasn't informed of your answer because you have forgotten to write @ pseudo.

Comment: Oh, forgive me, I didn't know one had to do that @JeanMarie

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the $2\pi$ is wrong.

Second, if you have a function that is an outcome of interference, then the same function but translated will have the same spectrum (meaning the absolute value of the Fourier coefficients will be the same) but you need to add to each wave a phase element for making the interference happen later or earlier.